# How to change tinymce scrollbar color?

Tags: css, tinymce

I changed my css in /tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/content.css

> scrollbar-base-color: #32332E;
>   scrollbar-arrow-color: #32332E;
>   scrollbar-3dlight-color: #3F423B;
>   scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #92968A;
>   scrollbar-face-color: #0A0909;
>   scrollbar-highlight-color: #1C1B1A;
>   scrollbar-shadow-color: #2B2A23;
>   scrollbar-track-color: #323038;

But it didn't make any sense.
I changed it to one color..
But its showing some default color.

There is no help in google about how to change tinymce scrollbar color.
Please help me..thnaks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only cross-browser compatible, standards compliant way to do that is to completely recreate it with JavaScript.  [Example](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar).